# alternatives such as plugins or other ways to achieve the "edit as a table" feature in Intellij community edition for .csv files

Tags: intellij-idea

so , i was looking into other options for the 'edit as a table' feature for working with *.csv files  in Intellij IDEA community edition but could not find any.Are there any other way to achieve this((like plugins)) or paying for ultimate edition is the only way

Comment: [CSV Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10037-csv-plugin)?

Comment: i have installed that but i cannot see the data in tabular form, if you can help me to configure the plugin that will be great.

Comment: I haven't used that plugin. Check the plugin's [README](https://github.com/SeeSharpSoft/intellij-csv-validator/blob/master/README.md) for details.